# Win32_NetworkAdapter Class returns NULL for boolean NetEnabled;

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, wmi

I am using this example of the WMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I retrieved information from the [Win32_NetworkAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods) like the Name, and MACAddress;

However, when I get boolean  NetEnabled; the vtProp VARIANT is NULL?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks. (Windows XP)

```
while (pEnumerator)                     
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if(0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;

    // Get the value of the Name property
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"NetEnabled", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0); //nothing filled into vtProp?
    wcout << " Net Enabled: " << vtProp.boolVal << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to:

> NetEnabled
>
> Data type: boolean
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Indicates whether the adapter is enabled or not. If True, the adapter is enabled. You can enable or disable the NIC by using the Enable and Disable methods.
>
> **Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000, and Windows NT 4.0:  This property is not available.**

Answer (score 1):

the `NetEnabled` property  is no available in windows xp, try using the [`NetConnectionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property instead.